# How to specify what happens for each trigger event in oracle pl sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

Hi I would like to know how I can specify what happens after each trigger event that the trigger monitors, for example:

```
create or replace trigger Trig_test
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
OF name
ON people
AFTER EACH ROW

begin 
IF INSERT then do this
ELSIF UPDATE then do this
END IF;
```

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance: J.C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it with `inserting`, `updating`, or `deleting`:

```
create or replace trigger Trig_test
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
OF name
ON people
AFTER EACH ROW
begin 
  if inserting
  then
    null;
  elsif updating
  then
    null;
  end if;
end;
```